# Trying to pull information from webpage

Tags: powershell, html-object, powershell-v6.0

I am trying to pull data from a website.  In my example case, I am running a search on Armorgames.com for the search term idle.  From there I would like to pull the name of each game and put it into a csv file for use later. My code:

```
$SearchResult = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://armorgames.com/search?type=games&q=idle' 
($SearchResult.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('H5') | Where { $_.pathname -like '/play*'})
```

Unfortunately, that won't output any results.  I can see the property names using:

```
$SearchResult.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('H5')
```

Using the tag 'a' I can find games with a pathname containing 'play'.But I am having trouble filtering the results and then outputting the results to a file

Answer (score 0):

```
$SearchResult.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') | where-Object -Property pathname -Like 'play/*'

# select property pathname
$SearchResult.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') | 
    Where-Object -Property pathname -Like 'play/*' |
        Select-Object -Property pathname

# select property title
$SearchResult.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') | 
    Where-Object -Property pathname -Like 'play/*' |
        Select-Object -Property title -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell Core (v6.0) compatible webscraping code, which should work with Windows PowerShell too, reliant on [regex with the -match operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) (as the `ParsedHtml` property isn't available on Core):

```
$SearchResult = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://armorgames.com/search?type=games&q=idle'
$GameNames = ($SearchResult.Content.split('<') | 
    where {$_ -match '^a href.*play.*\ title=.*>[A-Z].*'}) -replace '.*>'
$GameNames
```

The output looks like this:

```
Artist Idle
Hero Simulator: Idle Adventures
Idle Farmer
Idle Online Universe
Idle Sword
Idle Web Tycoon
Legendary Journey Idle
NGU IDLE
Religious Idle
Zombidle
```

Now that you have an array of the names you wanted, you should be able to create a CSV with whatever additional information you need.